# How can I use filter function like =FILTER(range/table name as ARRAY, cell reference as INCLUDE=1,"") as given in the snapshot below:

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I use filter function like [=FILTER(Table1,D18=1,"")} in detail =FILTER(range/table name as ARRAY, cell reference as INCLUDE=1,"") (=FILTER(Table1,D18=1,as given in the snapshot below:

[image: snapshot]

Comment: So what do you expect it to be doing?

Comment: Do you mean this maybe: `=IF(D18=1,Table1,"")` ?

Comment: This will not work: the criteria argument (second one) must have either the horizontal or vertical dimension of the array you want to filter. I think you need a different approach. As P.b already asked: what is your expected output.

Comment: not IF function, I want filter based on the cell value of the heading, i.e: filter AUDIT column by 1 (1 will be always same hence the column may change to SECRETARY or Purchasing, as in the snapshot)

Comment: So you mean to filter the table where the header equals the value in D18 and the values in given column equal 1, or should it filter to not empty?

Comment: Please share a picture of what you expect as a result for given example.

Comment: @MadhuPrakash you need to use a formula like this `=LET(_x,XLOOKUP(D18,A1:P1,A2:P16),FILTER(_x,_x=1))`

Comment: Or with table references: `=LET(x,XLOOKUP(D18,Table1[#Headers],Table1),FILTER(x,x=1))` or `=LET(x,XLOOKUP(D18,Table1[#Headers],Table1),FILTER(x,x<>""))`

Comment: This is very near to my query, but I need the value corresponding cell value from A column.

Comment: `=LET(x,XLOOKUP(D18,Table1[#Headers],Table1),FILTER(Table1,x<>""))`

Comment: Excepting result : If I am filtering SECRETARIAL by 1 and 3 result should be 3 and 1 and corresponding cell value from A:A (Secretarial and Clerical)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of using `XLOOKUP()` & `FILTER()` Function

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D19`

```
=FILTER(A2:A16,XLOOKUP(D18,B1:P1,B2:P16)=1)
```

---

If you need without blanks or 0's then,

[image]

---

```
=FILTER(A2:A16,XLOOKUP(D18,B1:P1,B2:P16)<>0)
```

---

### EDIT

As per comments of `OP`

[image]

---

[image]

• Formula used in cell `G19`

```
=LET(_x,XLOOKUP(G18,B1:P1,B2:P16),FILTER(HSTACK(A2:A16,_x),_x<>0))
```

---

Comment: The second one is fine, it is good if I got the corresponding numbers next to SECRETARIAL and Clerical.

Comment: Or, may be this `=LET(_x,XLOOKUP(D18,B1:P1,B2:P16),
FILTER(HSTACK(A2:A16,_x),_x<>0))`

Comment: Thank you so much dear all bit modified and done.

Comment: So glad to know it worked for you 

Comment: Is it possible to get the filtering horizontal?

Comment: That should be another new post. One post at a time.